# how to see why mockk assertEquals(...) fails

Tags: kotlin, mockk, mockk-verify

so i have a test like this:

```
verify {
            function.send(
                withArg { assertEquals(expected, actual) },
                withArg { assertEquals(expected, actual) })
}
```

and i'm wondering how can i easily see in stacktrace why the result was **-** (the diff between expected and actual object)

```
[1]: argument: ...responseCode=0003, usdAmount=12), matcher: matcher\<Transaction\>(), result: -
[2]: argument: CHARGEBACK, matcher: matcher\<Reason\>(), result: +

Stack trace:
io.mockk.impl.InternalPlatform.captureStackTrace (InternalPlatform.kt:125)
io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation (MockKStub.kt:250)
...
```

i already added settings as doc says:

```
stackTracesOnVerify=true
stackTracesAlignment=left
```

Comment: Why don’t you just add custom message to nested asserts, so that you know which one failed?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact case, you might be able to use capturing slots while verifying the calls. This would allow you to do the assertions outside of the `verify` block:

```kotlin
val firstArgument = slot<TypeOfFirst>()
val secondArgument = slot<TypeOfSecond>()

verify {
    function.send(capture(firstArgument), capture(secondArgument))
}

assertEquals(expected, firstArgument.captured)
assertEquals(expected, secondArgument.captured)
```

Note that, inside the `verify` block, this will now be equivalent to matching `function.send(any(), any())`, which could change the result when your actual `verify` block is more complicated (for example, matching multiple calls of the `send` function)